# Spring Integration Testing does not pick up JPA beans from other modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a multi module maven project. In one module I have all my persistence stuff like entities and repositories and in another module I import that persistence module and I want to run some integration tests.
The problem is that my tests do not pick up repositories and can't create the context because of the missing beans. Can someone help me with what I am missing?

The project structure looks like this

- persistence module
- business logic module
- web module

In my business logic module pom I import the persistence module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

My integration tests configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.acme.persistence", "com.acme.business"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DataTestConfig {

}
```

and all my tests are annotated with the following

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(DataTestConfig.class)
@DataJpaTest
```

If I move all the persistence module inside the business module then the tests work fine, but I want to keep them in separate modules.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried annotation them with `@SpringBootTest` ? can you show one test case with exception and stack trace

Comment: The tests are already annotated with @DataJpaTest. Why do I need to add @SpringBootTest?
The issue is that it cannot instantiate a service because it cannot find a repository.
The error looks something like this:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.acme.business.SomeService require a bean of type com.acme.persistence.SomeRepository

Comment: If you want integration testing then you need that annotation, why don't you post the code and error @CipQuestion

Comment: If I were to move the code from the persistence module into the business module and run the tests, then it will work, but I want to keep them separate.
There is a lot of code to post and I am trying to avoid that.
The idea is that all the services are inside the business module and repositories / entities in the persistence module. The business module imports the persistence module and I want to run some integration tests on the business module, but it fails to instantiate the services because of missing repository beans.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I added `@EnableJpaRepositories` on my test configuration class.
This way repositories were created and now my services that used repositories can be instantiated.
This is how the final integration testing configuration looks like

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.acme.persistence", "com.acme.business"})
@EntityScan("com.acme.persistence")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.acme.persistence")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DataTestConfig {

}
```